# Ffmpeg конвертация mp4 to 3gp

Tags: ffmpeg

Вообщем, нужно конвертировать mp4 файл в 3gp.
Выполняю команду

```
$exec = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s qcif -vcodec h263 -s 176x144 -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -r 25 -ab 32 -y outputfile.3gp');
print $exec;
```

И проблема в том, что 3gp файл выходит в 0байт. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: где знатоки?

Comment: Проверьте php.ini, в директиве disable_functions не должно быть прописано функции shell_exec.

Comment: @Deonis, тогда бы файл вообще не создавался  
@rnddev, это вопрос по ffmpeg, но не по php

Comment: @Etki, если ТС проверял именно файл, то да. Но если он ориентировался на "print $exec;", то вполне возможно (при определенном утановленном уровне ошибок), что возвращается не "null", а именно "0"

Comment: @Deonis я ориентировался на работоспособный файл после конвертации :)

Comment: Проверил команду — работает. Скорей всего с входным файлом проблемы. Запустите команду в консоли и пришлите вывод.
А ещё на некоторых системах кодек `aac` является экспериментальным — попробуйте добавить `-strict experimental`

Comment: @Jofsey благодарю, помогло.

Comment: @rnddev продублирую ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил команду — работает. Скорей всего с входным файлом проблемы. Запустите команду в консоли и пришлите вывод.

А ещё на некоторых системах кодек `aac` является экспериментальным.
Попробуйте добавить `-strict experimental`.

А ещё битрейт в 32 бита в секунду явно является слишком маленьким. Должно быть, вместо `-ab 32` вы имели в виду `-ab 32k`.

Comment: Появилась загвоздка. Сразу не проверил, видео конвертируется без звука.

Comment: @rnddev щас поправлю ответ :)

Comment: @Jofsey верно, спасибо. какой я не внимательный к мелочам :)